# show error of undefine root fragment tag in pop back stack in android app development

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In

```
fm.popBackStack([tag:ROOT_FRAGMENT_TAG],FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

the root fragment tag is not defined. I want to as is it depreciated in the latest version. If yes, then please tell me any alternative.

[image: here a pic]

I have searched on Google, YouTube, Android website and stack. I got many answers about popBackStack but it will not satisfy me because my problem about the root fragment tag in popBackStack that is not working but on a YouTube course that is uploaded 1 year ago it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends.Activity {
 
 private static final String.BACK_STACK_ROOT_TAG = "root_fragment";`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).